# Changing name of project is not reflected on GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have a java project which I work on using Eclipse ide.
I have renamed my project. This updated my .project file and I pushed it to GitHub.
But GitHub still shows old project name.

Is there any way to change name of project on GitHub?
I am using GitBash on windows to interact with Git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing your project name locally does not mean anything to Git or Github, you have to rename your project on Github itself and then update the references to your remote origin at the **.git/config** file in your local project.

Comment: You don't have to update them directly in the config, you can use `git remote set-url`